# how to write generic DB script to delete some data based on conditions from microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql

I have a user table and RoleUserMapReference tables
From RoleUserMapReference table has coulmn 'referenceId' and 'MapId', for 1 'mapId' multiple referenceId records are there I want to remove specific mapId data if multiple records found for mapId in RoleUserMapReference table. how to write generic query to delete these records

i.e RoleUserMapReference MapId referenceId
11                 100   1000
12                 100   1002
13                 101   1002
14                 100   1003

here mapId 100 is having 2 records ,so want to delete records where referenceId ='1000'

how to find and delete with query ?
please help

Comment: You want to delete all duplicate values or keep one row ? i mean if 100 got 2 times, then delete 2 rows or only one row.

Comment: mapId 100 is having 2 rows having 1000 and 1002 .... i want to delete row with value 1000 for all mapId.. do there can be MapId 101, 102,103 and each one can have 2 records i.e for ReferenceId 1000 and 1002 ..so for all mapId i want to delete record for referenceId =1000

Comment: pls provide table values, in description not good to see values.
if want to delete Referenceid 1000, then simply put 
"Delete from RoleUserMapReference  where referenceId ='1000' "

Answer (score 0):

Below script to delete duplicate values and keep only one rows.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    [MapId ],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY 
             [MapId]
        ORDER BY 
            [MapId]
    ) row_num
 FROM 
    RoleUserMapReference 
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE row_num = 1;
```